# Git revert file mode to 755

Tags: git, file, file-permissions

One of our devs somehow managed to change the file mode of a shell script from 755 to 644, and committed it to a branch on origin. I'd like to change it back to 755 but Git won't cooperate. I'm working in Linux bash, on Linux file system (within WSL2).

This is what I would expect should work (and in fact it *did* work on another branch created around the same time, that had the same change to the same file):

```
git checkout 716-confirmation-modal-dialog-when-deleting-a-form-or-a-form-field
git reset --hard origin/716-confirmation-modal-dialog-when-deleting-a-form-or-a-form-field
chmod 755 scripts/wait-for-it.sh
git add scripts/wait-for-it.sh
git push origin 716-confirmation-modal-dialog-when-deleting-a-form-or-a-form-field
```

Everything works up to the last step (the push). If I do a `git status` before the push, I get:

```
On branch 716-confirmation-modal-dialog-when-deleting-a-form-or-a-form-field
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/716-confirmation-modal-dialog-when-deleting-a-form-or-a-form-field'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   scripts/wait-for-it.sh
```

The push gives me the message "Everything up-to-date". After the push, `git status` tells me exactly the same, that `scripts/wait-for-it.sh` is modified; and the file has not been updated on origin.

I've tried setting `git config core.fileMode true`.

I also tried changing the file mode via `git update-index --chmod=+x scripts/wait-for-it.sh`.

`git config -l` gives:

```
user.email=**myemail**
user.name=Ben Whitmore
core.autocrlf=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://gitlab.coko.foundation/kotahi/kotahi.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main
branch.716-confirmation-modal-dialog-when-deleting-a-form-or-a-form-field.remote=origin
branch.716-confirmation-modal-dialog-when-deleting-a-form-or-a-form-field.merge=refs/heads/716-confirmation-modal-dialog-when-deleting-a-form-or-a-form-field
```

How can I fix this, or do I have to scrap the branch and start again?

Comment: `git add` adds it to the repo and lists it in the index, but you haven't made a commit yet, so Git doesn't know it's ready yet.

Comment: jthill means : run `git add`, **`git commit`** (<- the actions you list in your question miss that one), `git push`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by jthill, I needed to `git commit` before my `git push`. A silly oversight.